# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method with String

Tags: string, groovy, java.lang.class

I'm new to Groovy and I run into this error that I don't really understand.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: getUsers() is applicable for argument types: (String, String, String, String, String, String) values: [ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, ...]
Possible solutions: getUsers(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

This error happens when I called this method within another function that has the same parameters:

```
public List<String> getResponse(String userId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String address, String date) {
        try {
            def response = null;
            response = User.getUsers(userId, firstName, lastName, email, address, date)
        }
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is that method supposed to exist on that class?

Comment: Looks like the strings you’re working with aren’t Java strings. That’s why it says it can’t find the method with 6x String but does find it with 6x java.lang.String

Comment: Show how User.getUsers is declared.

Comment: Is getUsers a static method?

Comment: reveal your mystical and legendary User class!

Comment: @DaveNewton the method getResponse is in a different class than the getUsers one.

Comment: @Zastai how do I know that the strings belong to java.lang or not?
@tim_yates, no it's not static
@daggett here is how the User.getUsers is declared:
`public Object getUsers(String userId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String address, String date){}`
@injecteer it's a very big class with related to different classes so it's really hard to put everything up here.

Comment: @jasper Yes; I'm asking if `getUsers` is supposed to exist as a method on `User` (as opposed to an instance of `User`, or something/-where else entirely).

Comment: @jasper If it's not a static method then it needs to be accessed through an instance.

Comment: @jasper Try making that `public static` if you can. I’m a bit concerned that a method called `getUsers()` would return `Object`; that seems like very poor API.

Comment: Hi all, thank you so much for all the advices. So sorry not to reply any sooner since I'm a bit busy lately. I finally solve the issue. There was a typo when calling the method.